# Как вывести простое окно pyqt5 до старта основного приложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Как сделать простое окно ошибки до старта основного приложения на pyqt5?

Примерно так:

```
if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() == 0:  
   #вывод окна
```

Основа написана по этому примеру:

```
import sys
from gui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    def MyFunction(self):
        pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то как то так.

```
import sys
import ctypes
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Простое приложение."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ##################
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 332, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle("Приложение PyQt5")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() == 0:
        # если условие ложно
        # сообщение об ошибке
        QMessageBox.critical(QWidget(), 'Ошибка!', "Запрещено!")
    else:
        # иначе запустить приложение
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: можно упомянуть наверху ответа, что суть решения это QMessageBox.critical у вас, а MainWindow может что угодно содержать (не имеет отношения к вопросу).

Comment: jfs: Спасибо что вы это сделали за меня ) Я просто привёл самодостаточный пример, запустил человек скрипт у него сразу всё заработало и он  с энтузиазмом двинулся дальше.

Comment: [~95% на Stack Overflow из поисковиков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/23044) поэтому ответы не только и не столько для авторов вопросов пишутся.

Comment: Я если честно не совсем понимаю куда вы клоните просто скажите как мне правильно надо было ответить на вопрос ?

Comment: в первом комментарии упомянул *что* нужно сделать, во втором — *почему*.